# Regular Expression for Money format

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written a regular expression as

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,3})?\s*$
```

for money format with accepting one dot but I need to accept the commas too. So how to modify the above regular expression for accepting commas?

EXamples:1,20,000.000
2,000.000
3,30,30,000.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modiyf it to this:

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d+[,\.\d]+$
```

Comment: Hi Amit it is failing when i am giving value as 1,20,000.000

Comment: Why not simply use "([\d\.,]*)" it will match all set of digits [0-9] as well as dot and comma.

Comment: @smirnov, that regex would match `.,.,.,`

Answer (score 0):

Try "(\d{1,3}[,.])+\d{3}"

```
string pattern = @"(\d{1,3}[,.])+\d{3}";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
string s = "1,20,000.000 2,000.000 3,30,30,000.000";

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Demo: http://dotnetfiddle.net/lTaBbV